# "Convert" ElasticsearchRepository-method to NativeSearchQuery

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

we used springboot with springdata and elasticsearch. We've a ElasticsearchRepository interface with methods defined.

e.g.

```
List<Location> findByCityCode(String cityCode, Pageable pageable);
```

Now we want to "scroll" throw the results. Therefore we use the NativeSearchQueryBuilder and ElasticsearchTemplate.

e.g.

```
NativeSearchQuery matchAll = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withIndices("locations")
    .withQuery(matchAllQuery())
    .withPageable(PageRequest.of(0,10000))
    .build();


ScrolledPage<Location> scrolledResult = 
   (ScrolledPage<Location>) elasticsearchTemplate.startScroll(1000L, matchAll, Location.class);
```

Is there a way to use the method from the interface for the query in the second code or do we have to "rewrite" all querys with a querybuilder?